# when I say something shortly. is it sounds rude?

Tags: meaning-in-context

when I say something shortly. is it sounds rude?
Of course I think it depends on situation. however, 
I really wonder if it is a wrong way to talk to someone. 
I work in the hotel and need to keep talking samething all the time.
such as when I order a breakfast or people want to check out, I usally say:

Would you like to have breakfast? 
Would you like to have a cup of coffe?

but it is too long for keeping saying same thing all the time. so if it is ok, 
then I want to make it short like :

Breakfast sir? (Would you like to have breakfast?)
coffee sir? (Would you like to have a cup of coffe?)
cheking out? (Would you like to check out?).
and anything else? (Do you have more question?)

or is this ok in english?

and I usually call the guest as ma'am or sir. and sometimes if a female person
is young I call her "miss". is this also proper way to call them?

Comment: *opinion-based*

Comment: The polite way to put it is ["*I'm sorry you don't know what brevity looks like*"](http://code.jsoftware.com/mediawiki/images/8/8e/Be55f5806cb901301d46001dd8b71c47.gif) ;)

Comment: Tone of voice and attitude determine whether you are being rude in this case.  "Coffe, sir?" said nicely is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like what you're doing is perfectly acceptable as well-mannered english. You're not being rude at all.